# Recover deleted files on mac

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I have removed the file by command line

`rm -rf myScript.sh`

How can I recover this file? Is there a way to recover from command line because these recovery tools take too much time scanning. I need to recover it immediately.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a TimeMachine backup or other backup of the file, it's gone. If you know the exact content of part of the file, you might be able to find it, but `rm` doesn't have any sort of "recycle bin" from which you can recover the things it removes.

Comment: at the moment, i haven't used TimeMachine backup. Is there another way to fix it ?

Comment: @minhcat_vo: If you don't have a backup and you don't have the time to run file-recovery tools, your file is gone.